# Python script (includes pandas, sqlite, numpy, sklearn) started throwing "Killed: 9" error (has been working for months before)

Tags: python, macos, memory, kernel

I have a script that I run almost daily without issue. Usually I run the script inside of Jupyter but then I started getting the error:

"Kernel has died, will restart automatically"

So then I tried running in from the command line and I got the error:

"Killed: 9"

I did some digging and it seems this means that the OOM Manager is killing my process (I'm on a Mac). Now while my app / script is fairly memory intensive, it has been running fine for months now without issue (I also have 16 GB of memory and an app that manages free memory and while running, it never really gets below 1 GB).

I do have one idea as to what caused this but I don't have the technical understanding to confirm it nor can I find any information online. When I was running the script the other day, my computer died mid-process. I'm not sure exactly where it died but it was somewhere around reading or writing to a sqlite database or resampling a pandas dataframe.

The error immediately started happening after that happened.

But I'm not really sure what to do now... I've been Googling for days and have now tried most of the troubleshooting I can find online. Is it a bug in my kernel? Did I somehow screw up the kernel to cause this? How might I diagnose this? I see some people analyzing the logs to figure it out but I'm not sure how to access them or read them.

**Any help would be really appreciated!!!**

Comment: Most likely you're running out of memory. Try reading your logs https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26480/where-can-i-find-my-crash-logs

Comment: Thanks @MarkSegal! Is there something in particular I should be looking for? I've never looked through these before so I'm not very familiar.

Comment: perhaps try running python 64 bit, or figure out why you're running out of memory.